# which TDD unit testing framework is best for angular + AEM code base?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, aem

we have a huge E commerce application and the code base is Angular 1.5.8 component based structure on AEM. I am new to TDD but wanted to understand what and how can I proceed to build a TDD framework on application.

Comment: You're probably mixing TDD with testing itself. TDD is not connected to any framework directly

Comment: TDD is a methodolog, not a framework.  AEM is Java based so lots of frameworks out there to follow TDD. For JS and client side stuff there are further options available. There is no single best approcah answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of "how to do TDD in Angular" is more about your actions and mental approach as a developer rather than what frameworks you use. You don't mention if you mean AngularJS or Angular 2, but I suppose with either you would be best off writing units testing with Jasmine or Mocha library and run them with Karma. For e2e / ui tests there is Protractor with it's own API's.

Here are some links you may find useful:

**TDD For AngularJS**

- https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-angular-test-driven-development
- http://andyshora.com/unit-testing-best-practices-angularjs.html
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/test-driven-development-in-angularjs--cms-25108

**TDD For Angular 2**

- https://keyholesoftware.com/2016/05/16/test-driven-intro-angular2/
- https://semaphoreci.com/community/series/test-driven-development-with-angular-2-and-webpack
- https://github.com/DanH91/tdd-angular2
- https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/